# Looking up values of one csv file camparing if it is present in any column in another file and print the whole row in new csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my first csv file(authors list)(single column)

> Aaron Harwood
>
> Kenji Kaneda

This is my second csv file(sigle column)

> Aaron Harwood|Rajiv Ranjan|Rajkumar Buyya
>
> Alejandro Pérez-Méndez|Antonio Fernandez Gómez-Skarmeta|Gabriel
> López|Óscar Cánovas Reverte
>
> Akinori Yonezawa|Kenji Kaneda|Kenjiro Taura
>
> Aaron Harwood|abcd
>
> Kenji Kaneda|abcde
>
> Aaron Harwood|lxkc

Now I want to print all the rows with given authors name in another .csv file. How do I go on about doing it?

I have tried this

```
import pandas

authors = []
with open("Book1.csv", "r",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    r = pandas.read_csv(f)
    authors = list(r["author"])

i=0

with open("trialall.csv", "r",encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
        if authors[i] in line:
            i=i+1
            with open("newer.csv", "a", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f2:
                f2.write(line)
                f2.write("\n")
                print("doing")
```

Please suggest changes. I am expecting an output csv which will have these rows

> Aaron Harwood|Rajiv Ranjan|Rajkumar Buyya
>
> Akinori Yonezawa|Kenji Kaneda|Kenjiro Taura
>
> Aaron Harwood|abcd
>
> Kenji Kaneda|abcde
>
> Aaron Harwood|lxkc

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to `open` each file, because pandas does that for you.  Since I don't have your `.csv` to work from, I will just outline the structure so that it's easy to adapt any minor changes.

You can do simply

```
authors = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv")["authors"]
df = pd.read_csv("trialall.csv")
df["authors"] = df.str.split("|")
```

Then you simply do

```
filter = df["authors"].apply(lambda x: any([item in k for item in x]))
df[filter].write_csv("newer.csv")
```